# melville and its child theme

Tags: child-theme

hello guys im making child theme of [melville](http://madebyraygun.com/wordpress/themes/melville/) and i wanna make a custom page with a static menu (as in not made with wp )  of my own and under it i wanna display the content and i use this `get_template_part('loop' ,'home-page')`where the home-page its name of my custom page and i do have the loop file in my child theme please if anyone knows whats my msitake i would be thankfull

my issue is the content doesnt show up

Edit : here's my code im using nothing fancy

`

```
 get_header(); ?>
        some xhtml here 

    <?php get_template_part('loop' ,'home-page') ?>
    <?php //comments_template( '', true ); ?>

 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

`

Comment: Please post code examples of what is and isn't working. It is really hard to troubleshoot `it's not working` without more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) your file needs to be called `childtheme/loop-home-page.php` if you did just then  `<?php get_template_part('loop' ,'home-page') ?>`you would call it loop.php  not sure if that helps at all.

Another thing is make sure your page is using your custom template file as this could also be your problem. What is the name of your custom page file? if it's home.php this may be the problem.